# Add colorbar for polygones in basemap plot of US

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, python-3.6

Any help with drawing the colorbar for below code is highly appreciated. [I want my figure to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPTSx.png)

I am using shape file along with below mentioned file to draw color map based on density available in the dictionary object.

```
            {'ALABAMA': 37,
             'ALASKA': 1,
             'ARIZONA': 161,
             'ARKANSAS': 35,
             'CALIFORNIA': 1854,
             'COLORADO': 104,
             'CONNECTICUT': 170,
             'DELAWARE': 53,
             'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA': 83,
             'FLORIDA': 364,
             'GEORGIA': 350,
             'HAWAII': 15,
             'IDAHO': 16,
             'ILLINOIS': 553,
             'INDIANA': 109,
             'IOWA': 60,
             'KANSAS': 47,
             'KENTUCKY': 50,
             'LOUISIANA': 48,
             'MAINE': 17,
             'MARYLAND': 187,
             'MASSACHUSETTS': 351,
             'MICHIGAN': 260,
             'MINNESOTA': 170,
             'MISSISSIPPI': 16,
             'MISSOURI': 119,
             'NA': 11,
             'NEBRASKA': 28,
             'NEVADA': 21,
             'NEW HAMPSHIRE': 32,
             'NEW JERSEY': 676,
             'NEW MEXICO': 20,
             'NEW YORK': 993,
             'NORTH CAROLINA': 266,
             'NORTH DAKOTA': 5,
             'OHIO': 271,
             'OKLAHOMA': 32,
             'OREGON': 77,
             'PENNSYLVANIA': 367,
             'PUERTO RICO': 5,
             'RHODE ISLAND': 37,
             'SOUTH CAROLINA': 40,
             'SOUTH DAKOTA': 9,
             'TENNESSEE': 95,
             'TEXAS': 954,
             'UTAH': 52,
             'VERMONT': 10,
             'VIRGINIA': 278,
             'WASHINGTON': 351,
             'WEST VIRGINIA': 10,
             'WISCONSIN': 127,
             'WYOMING': 3}
```

Here is my code

```
            import matplotlib as mpl
            from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
            fig,ax=plt.subplots()


            m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)
            # draw state boundaries.

            shp_info = m.readshapefile('st99_d00','states',drawbounds=True)


            popdensity = top10states.set_index('STATES').to_dict()['NOOFAPPS']




            # choose a color for each state based on population density.
            legendcolor = []
            colors={}
            statenames=[]
            patches = []

            cmap = plt.cm.summer 
            vmin = min(top10states["NOOFAPPS"])
            vmax = max(top10states["NOOFAPPS"]) 

            # norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=False)
            # mapper=mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)


            for shapedict in m.states_info:
                statename = shapedict['NAME'].upper()
                if statename in popdensity:
                    pop = popdensity[statename]
                    colors[statename] = cmap(1.-np.sqrt((pop-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)))[:3]
                    statenames.append(statename)
                else:
                    statenames.append(statename)
                    colors[statename] = "darkorange"

            ax = plt.gca() # get current axes instance
            fig = plt.gcf()




            for nshape,seg in enumerate(m.states):

                color = rgb2hex(colors[statenames[nshape]]) 
                legendcolor.append(color)
                poly = Polygon(seg,facecolor=color,edgecolor=color)
                ax.add_patch(poly)
                patches.append(poly)

            mappble = plt.gci()

            # p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=cmap)
            # p.set_array(np.array(legendcolor))
            # cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(fig,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,orientation="horizontal")
            # cb = fig.colorbar.ColorbarBase(fig,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,orientation="horizontal")

            # fig.colorbar.ColorbarBase(fig,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,orientation="horizontal")
            # map.colorbar(norm=norm)
            plt.title('Filling State Polygons by Population Density')
            plt.show()
```

I have tried few of the commented combinations and nothing seems to be working for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have construct custom colorbar based on values of your density dict with `ColorbarBase` function. Values you have to convert via `ScalarMappable`. Look at the comments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.colors import rgb2hex, Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)
ax = plt.gca() 
fig = plt.gcf()
shp_info = m.readshapefile('st99_d00','states',drawbounds=True)

popdensity = {'ALABAMA': 37,
 'ALASKA': 1,
 'ARIZONA': 161,
 'ARKANSAS': 35,
 'CALIFORNIA': 1854,
 'COLORADO': 104,
 'CONNECTICUT': 170,
 'DELAWARE': 53,
 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA': 83,
 'FLORIDA': 364,
 'GEORGIA': 350,
 'HAWAII': 15,
 'IDAHO': 16,
 'ILLINOIS': 553,
 'INDIANA': 109,
 'IOWA': 60,
 'KANSAS': 47,
 'KENTUCKY': 50,
 'LOUISIANA': 48,
 'MAINE': 17,
 'MARYLAND': 187,
 'MASSACHUSETTS': 351,
 'MICHIGAN': 260,
 'MINNESOTA': 170,
 'MISSISSIPPI': 16,
 'MISSOURI': 119,
 'NA': 11,
 'NEBRASKA': 28,
 'NEVADA': 21,
 'NEW HAMPSHIRE': 32,
 'NEW JERSEY': 676,
 'NEW MEXICO': 20,
 'NEW YORK': 993,
 'NORTH CAROLINA': 266,
 'NORTH DAKOTA': 5,
 'OHIO': 271}

nodata_color = "darkorange"
colors={}
statenames=[]
patches = []

cmap = plt.cm.summer
vmin = min(popdensity.values()); vmax = max(popdensity.values())
norm = Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
# color mapper to covert values to colors
mapper = ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

for shapedict in m.states_info:
    statename = shapedict['NAME'].upper()
    if statename in popdensity:
        pop = popdensity[statename]
        colors[statename] = mapper.to_rgba(pop)
        statenames.append(statename)
    else:
        statenames.append(statename)
        colors[statename] = nodata_color

for nshape,seg in enumerate(m.states):
    color = rgb2hex(colors[statenames[nshape]]) 
    poly = Polygon(seg,facecolor=color,edgecolor=color)
    if (colors[statenames[nshape]] == nodata_color):
        p_no = poly
    ax.add_patch(poly)
plt.title('Filling State Polygons by Population Density')

# put legend for no data states
if p_no is not None:
    plt.legend((p_no,), ('No data',))

# construct custom colorbar
cax = fig.add_axes([0.27, 0.1, 0.5, 0.05]) # posititon
cb = ColorbarBase(cax,cmap=cmap,norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
cb.ax.set_xlabel('Population density of U.S.A.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I guess horizontal colorbar is more suitable for your map.

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the color bar using dark green to indicate heavily populated areas? And vice versa. Thanks! @Serenity

Comment: A Colormap has reversed version, just add _r postfix to the colormap name